# How to disable cell sellection in UICollectionview

Tags: swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

I have a collectionView, when an selected item, I want this item cannot be operated,
How can i solve this? someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
collectionView.allowsSelection = false

// or 

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, shouldSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    <do your code here>
}
```